# Trying to post array causes notice: Uninitialized string offset

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below form (excerpt)

```
 <tr>

        <td><?php echo "$navn";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$navn";?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo "$primaereMuskelgruppe";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$primaereMuskelgruppe";?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo "$sekundaereMuskelgruppe";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$sekundaereMuskelgruppe";?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo "$redskab";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$redskab";?>"></td>
        <?php
        switch ($antalReps) {
            case 'Alle':?>
        <td><?php echo "$vaegt12reps";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$vaegt12reps";?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo "$vaegt10reps";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$vaegt10reps";?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo "$vaegt8reps";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$vaegt8reps";?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo "$vaegt6reps";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$vaegt6reps";?>"></td>
                <?php break;?>
            <?php case 12:?>
        <td><?php echo "$vaegt12reps";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$vaegt12reps";?>"></td>
                 <?php break;?>
            <?php case 10:?>
        <td><?php echo "$vaegt10reps";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$vaegt10reps";?>"></td>
                 <?php break;?> 
        <?php case 8:?>
        <td><?php echo "$vaegt8reps";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$vaegt8reps";?>"></td>
                 <?php break;?> 
             <?php case 6:?>
        <td><?php echo "$vaegt6reps";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$vaegt6reps";?>"></td>
                 <?php break;
                            }
        ?>
        <td><?php echo "$inkrementering";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$inkrementering";?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="historik[]"><br></td>

        <?php 

             } 
             }
                ?>
    </tr>
</table>           
   <input type="submit" value="Gem træning" name="submit">
</form>
```

The form table can have 1-->many rows. All columns except the last one is read-only.

When the user clicks submit, I want it to post to a different page with a number of 'historik'-arrays, one for each row.

And then, on the next page, I want to go through each array like:

```
foreach ($_POST['historik'] as $historikArray)
{
    echo $historikArray;
```

When I do the above, the output seems ok - I get what looks like an array of data for each row in previous form.

But, when I do something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['historik'] as $historikArray)
{
    echo $historikArray[3];
```

I would expect it to run through each array (i.e each row from previous form) and display array item number 3 for each array.

Instead, it echoes the third character of every piece of data from each field of each row/array, along with a notice. Below I've posted two rows from the table, with the 3rd character of each field in each row...

```
n
s
c
g
0
0

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3 in D:\Programmer\Xampp\htdocs\styrkesite\modtagHistorik.php on line 16

s
s
c
n
0
0

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3 in D:\Programmer\Xampp\htdocs\styrkesite\modtagHistorik.php on line 16
```

Apparently, I'm posting a string for each row, and not an array(?)

Can anyone help? Also, ideally I would like to use an associative array, but I don't know how to in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed posting strings. You cant post arrays. You can first serialize the array to a string then unserialize it after the post.

change:

```
<td><?php echo "$navn";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo "$navn";?>"></td>
```

To:

```
<td><?php echo "$navn";?><input type="hidden" name="historik[]" value="<?php echo base64_encode(serialize($navn));?>"></td>
```

Then in your loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['historik'] as $historikArray)
    {
    echo unserialize(base64_decode($historikArray))[3];
```

Comment: Hmm, not quite there yet, I'm afraid. I getting the error: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 4 bytes

The array/string contains '.' in some of the entries, like 50.50 as a decimal number - could that cause an issue?

Comment: I edited it to use base64 encode/decode. That will fix the problem with decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your html creates an array of strings not an array of arrays

$_POST['historik'] is an array

Inside the for each loop the variable you have called historikArray is a string.

Try doing a print_r or var_dump on $_POST to see what is in it.

Comment: I did a var_dump and got the following result: array(6) { [0]=> string(4) "s:6:" [1]=> string(4) "s:4:" [2]=> string(4) "s:0:" [3]=> string(4) "s:7:" [4]=> string(4) "s:5:" [5]=> string(4) "s:4:" } 

Looks fine compared to the table they're from - except that the two last 'strings' are actually the numbers 55.00 and 2.50. Do you know if it's correct that these two decimal numbers are recognized as strings?